# Call service methods from activity without binding

Tags: android, aidl

I have a push service running for my application responsible for keeping the TCP connection alive and create notifications on incoming messages.

I need this service to run even if the activity is closed, so the solution posted online was to call `startService()` instead of `bind()`, and indeed this solves the problem of the service ending on activity destroyed.

However with no Binder how can I call methods of my service? One way I've managed to get to work is through `BroadcastReceiver`. Is there a simpler way to achieve such a behaviour?

Comment: You can alternatively use a LocalBroadcastManager (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) or use a powerful eventbus like otto (https://square.github.io/otto/) or greenrobot (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add an action you use to call `startService`, one for every different method/case you want to call/handle, and retrieve it with `intent.getAction()`, when `onStartCommand` is called

From the documentation of [startService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent))

> Every call to this method will result in a corresponding call to the
>   target service's onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method, with the
>   intent given here. This provides a convenient way to submit jobs to a
>   service without having to bind and call on to its interface.

Comment: The service is there all the time (in theory) once the application is launched the service will remain running. So wouldn't this only work in the case that I start the service it does a task based on intent.getAction() then it finishes then it starts again does another task and so on?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The first time you call startService it will be instantiated. If the service is already running it not instantiated anymore

Comment: Ah, okay now it makes perfect sense, what I thought is that onStart is only called once, and calling startService again would stop and restart the service. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant sorry

Comment: I just wanted to be sure,